# Errors when try to InstantiateViewController after button click

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm beginner on Xamarin iOS development using Visual Studio 2015 and I found my first doubt/problem.

When I try to load a TabController embed in a NavigationController after click on a button, I'm getting a black screen with white tab bar at bottom (no image or any configutarion is showing).

This is my Storyboard (It has NavigationController -> TabBarController -> 4 ViewControllers (HomeController, SearchController, MoreController, SettingController)):

[image]

All components have StoryBoard ID.

In Previous Controller, My code to PushViewController is something like this:

```
WorkspaceNavigationController controller = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("WorkspaceNavigationController") as WorkspaceNavigationController;
if (controller != null)
{
    controller.PushViewController(controller, true);
}
```

But I'm getting a black screen :S. In my output windows, I can see "errors" related with the viewcontrollers: "Unknown class HomeController in interface Builder file" and the same with the others.

EDIT: Ok, the black screen is showing because my WorkspaceNavigationController was inheriting from UIViewController. Now, is inheriting from UINavigationController and I get this error: "Pushing a navigation controller is not supported"

I think I cannot use the PushViewController with NavigationController, But I try to do the same with TabBarController, with this code:

```
TabBarController controller = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("TabBarController") as TabBarController;
if (controller != null)
{
    controller.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true);
}
```

And the error is another: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key HomeController."

EDIT: I changed the call of NavigationController with the controller obtained, but it seems has no NavigationController, because it has null value

Really, I don't understand how I could show this. And I'm not understanding the behaviour of that (Because both (Navigation and TabBar controllers) are inheriting of UIViewController). Could you give me a solution and how to understand this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the correct way is

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourController, animated: true)
```

your `selectedViewController` is actually a `UINavigationViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: Follow this

1. Make sure you have your `WorkspaceNavigationController` class file.
2. Select the storyboard file of that `NavigationController` and also make sure to select the yellow (left from the upper three icons of the storyboard file)
3. And then make sure, you have introduced the proper class file to that `NavigationController` view.

I've added image for better understanding.

[image: help image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks in advance for your fast answer! I'm working on VS 2015 and I have selected the class in Properties -> Widget -> Identity -> Class.

I have a WorkspaceNavigationController.cs class in my solution explorer